# UIWebViews and shouldStartLoadWithRequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hyperlink

I have a `UIWebView` with a link that looks like this: [Visit website](http://www.website.com).  In the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method, is there a way to grab the words "Visit website" rather than the URL?  I'd like to use this text as a basis for some custom functionality in relation to some `UIWebViews`.

Thanks

Comment: does your URL has "Visit website" as substring

Comment: Unfortunately not, the text I'd like to grab is only found 'outside' the URL itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method there is obviously no way to get what you want. Its very easy to understand - that method receives mostly the `URL` and thats it and the text you want to get is a part of html tag of html page. To achieve your needs it seems like you need to parse html page and when some url is clicked (like in `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method) you have to find the corresponding html tag (`<a href>`) to find out what is the text inside this tag (it is something like `<a ref=someurl>Visit da page</a>`)